# What is this pink-flowering plant found in Shanghai, China in March?

Tags: botany, species-identification

This plant appears to have fleshy protrusions resembling flowers growing out of its stem (although I am unable to identify them as such).

Does anyone know the identity of these plants?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this is the Chinese Redbud (*[Cercis chinensis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercis_chinensis)*), see this image (from here):

[image]